# Why is "current_question" being treated as an object? When I run my code it says type(str)

Tags: python, oop

So the solution code is this:

```
class QuizBrain:

    def __init__(self, q_list):
        self.question_number = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.question_list = q_list

    def still_has_questions(self):
        return self.question_number < len(self.question_list)

    def next_question(self):
        current_question = self.question_list[self.question_number]
        print(type(current_question))
        self.question_number += 1
        user_answer = input(f"Q.{self.question_number}: {current_question.text} (True/False): ")
        self.check_answer(user_answer, current_question.answer)

    def check_answer(self, user_answer, correct_answer):
        if user_answer.lower() == correct_answer.lower():
            self.score += 1
            print("You got it right!")
        else:
            print("That's wrong.")
        print(f"The correct answer was: {correct_answer}.")
        print(f"Your current score is: {self.score}/{self.question_number}")
        print("\n")
```

Regarding the method next_question(self), current_question is being regarded as an object, whereas in my attempt it is a string. What is making current_question in the solution an object? I will show the main.py code below there is also a question_model.py with the following:

question_model.py

```py
class Question:

    def __init__(self, q_text, q_answer):
        self.text = q_text
        self.answer = q_answer
```

main.py

```py
from question_model import Question
from data import question_data
from quiz_brain import QuizBrain

question_bank = []
for question in question_data:
    question_text = question["question"]
    question_answer = question["correct_answer"]
    new_question = Question(question_text, question_answer)
    question_bank.append(new_question)

quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)

while quiz.still_has_questions():
    quiz.next_question()

print("You've completed the quiz")
print(f"Your final score was: {quiz.score}/{quiz.question_number}")
```

I hope my question makes sense, I'm a noobie. I can copy/paste my code if that helps but I believe all I need to know is how current_question is being considered an object. I don't see it set equal to a class anywhere.

Thank you

Comment: For one thing, everything in python is an object.

Comment: What output are you getting? Why is it wrong?

Comment: What does "in my attempt" mean? How are you running this code?

Comment: Answering questions like these, and learning to ask them yourself, will help clarify your thought process, which will in turn make you a better coder.

Comment: current_question contains an element of q_list. and q_list is a list of Question instances.  You might then want to access `current_question.text` or `current_question.answer`.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for additional help

Comment: " I don't see it set equal to a class anywhere". You do it here: `new_question = Question(question_text, question_answer)` then you make a list of Question objects `question_bank.append(new_question)`  and you pass this list to the QizBrain constructor `quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your response, if you read through it again you might be able to see what I am asking, though I know I can always ask questions better, that will come in time with greater understanding. Sembei Norimaki answered it quite nicely, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Python is an object-oriented programming language. Everything in Python is treated as an object, including variable, function, list, tuple, dictionary, set, etc.

> Edit:

As pointed out by [Sembei Norimaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261062/sembei-norimaki) if you do `type("fre")` it will return a str not an object.

**Here is why:**

`type()` checks the type of the object. Which in this case is a string.

The `type()` function either returns the type of the object or returns a new type object based on the arguments passed.

From [the official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/): **"With one argument, return the type of an object."**

Comment: if you do `type("fre")` it will return str not object